# How can I change which AD account an Exchange mailbox is connected to without deleting the account?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010

I would like to move an Exchange 2010 mailbox from mydomain\userAccount1 to mydomain\userAccount2 without deleting userAccount1.

I have seen numerous articles online that talk about how to do this after userAccount1 is deleted but none that provide steps to move a mailbox with all its e-mail, active sync relationships, and other metadata over to a different active directory user account.

How can I move a mailbox from mydomain\userAccount1 to mydomain\userAccount2 without deleting userAccount1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try to performs these steps:

1. removing Exchange attributes for userAccount1 using the Disable-Mailbox cmdlet
2. running Clean-MailboxDatabase
3. reconnecting the mailbox to userAccount2 using the Connect-Mailbox cmdlet

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest i could find.  I am not sure that it will be what you're looking for, but it might be able to help.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298174.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maxwells answer dated 2012/05/02 @ 14:09 is correct.

Quoted directly from the ['Disable-Mailbox' online link](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/33be55a3-1880-437d-a631-c1cca1736421%28EXCHG.141%29.aspx):

> The Disable-Mailbox cmdlet removes the mailbox's Exchange attributes from Active Directory. The **mailbox isn't deleted and can be reconnected** to its user at a later date by using the Connect-Mailbox cmdlet.